# Cannot see images on Mathematics Stack Exchange

Tags: support, images

I am not able to see images in *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)* Stack Exchange posts on my home computer (Windows/Chrome). In fact I can see the images during about 1 second after opening a question but then they disappear in all posts.

This problem is not observed on all other devices in use.

What can be the reason? I have searched through meta and already checked that imgur.com is not blocked.

An example:
[Prove that ratio is $k=2/5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4386770/prove-that-ratio-is-k-2-5)

Here is what I see (Note: I cannot see now the image below! :)

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to a hint from @Robert Longson in the comments, I have found that the problem was caused by [the following extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/urban-free-vpn-proxy/eppiocemhmnlbhjplcgkofciiegomcon?hl=en). Surprisingly, the extension being not active nevertheless suppresses the images on all sites of Stack Exchange/Overflow community.